# Can gasoline and frozen orange juice concentrate make napalm?

Tags: explosives

In the movie [Fight Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club), the character Tyler Durden says that equal parts gasoline and frozen orange juice concentrate make [napalm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napalm). The question's very simple; would this mixture make napalm, anything like napalm, or a precursor to it? My guess is it wouldn't work, and would *reek*.

Comment: A little bit of both actually; I think the OJ will reduce the flammability of the gasoline, and the combination won't be the sticky goo we think of as napalm.

Comment: I'll check the DVD commentary later, but my recollection is that the recipes for explosives, etc were changed for safety reasons.

Comment: IIRC the one they were most worried about was dynamite (later on after the liposuction clinic scene), so they left out some key steps of the glycerine-making and nitroglycerine-making process. However, the idea of napalm from gasoline and OJ is mentioned only once almost as a throwaway, to clue you in about what this guy thinks about when he's at home and the power goes out.

Comment: From an [interview with Chuck Palahniuk](http://www.dvdtalk.com/interviews/chuck_palahniuk.html) (he wrote the book): `Well, Ed Norton changed one ingredient in every one to make them useless. So, that really pissed me off because I really research those really well. Actually its styrofoam and gasoline...`

Comment: Yeah, I knew about that one; you add some long-chain polymers back into the gasoline solvent (synthetic rubber works really well too) and you get a sticky, flammable tar.

Comment: I guess I have my answer; Oliver-C's comment says that the orange juice concentrate was a substitute for the real second ingredient, styrofoam.

Comment: @KeithS - You should feel free to write this up as a full answer if you have an answer to your own question. That is if nobody else want to do it!

Comment: Styrofoam and Gasoline are a much more effective combination.

Comment: @Jamiec: I did, and for some reason the post was converted to a comment by the moderator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Credit to Oliver_C*

From an [interview with Chuck Palahniuk](http://www.dvdtalk.com/interviews/chuck_palahniuk.html) (he wrote the book):

> Well, Ed Norton changed one ingredient in every one to make them useless. So, that really pissed me off because I really research those really well. Actually its styrofoam and gasoline...